# Do I need bind9 for dns router computer?

Tags: 16.04, server, internet, dhcp, interface

I have done dhcp, interfaces, etc correctly as far as know. Each version of changes ends up with no access to the internet. So I am missing something. Could if be that I need to install bind9 to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't **need** bind9. You need a DNS server. You may use a public DNS server, like [1.1.1.1](https://1.1.1.1), for every client, or you may set up a DNS server, like bind, locally.

That said - for simple networks it's probably better to use [dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq). dnsmasq will automagically handle setting reverse records, forward records and so on, so that you can go by name internally in your network.

This is certainly possible with bind and dhcpd as well, but bind is more complex. It's also more powerful. If you have a single subnet, this extra complexity is usually not worth it.

If you don't need local name resolution, you can just set the dns-server in the dhcpd.conf to for instance 1.1.1.1, and it should work.

Comment: Then I could unmark dnsmasq in the following?  '# nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 

[main] 
plugins.ifupdown,keyfile,ofono 
#dns.dnsmasq 

[ifupdown] 
managed=true'

Comment: Leaving the # off of dns.dnsmasg solved some of my problems. Thanks vidarlo for trying.